# F#: Remove an event that was added in code I don't control

Tags: f#

I'm working with F# and ScottPlot, and I need to replace ScottPlot's built-in right click event with my own. As ScottPlot's website describes (https://scottplot.net/faq/right-click-menu/), to do this I need to remove their provided `DefaultRightClickEvent` using something like `formsPlot1.RightClicked -= formsPlot1.DefaultRightClickEvent;`.

However, F# is not letting me do this. There is no 'Remove' I can pass `DefaultRightClickEvent` to, and besides the info on 'Add' makes it very clear it is permanent.  I don't have an EventHandler to use and can't create one from `DefaultRightClickEvent` because it accepts arguments in the form `(obj * EventArgs)` instead of `obj -> EventArgs`, and `plot.RightClicked.RemoveHandler(new EventHandler(fun obj args -> plot.DefaultRightClickEvent(obj, args)))` doesn't work.

Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, basically what [MrD at KookerellaLtd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088029/mrd-at-kookerellaltd) suggested, I created the plot in a C# project, removed the event handler, and returned the modified plot to the F# code. Thanks for your suggestions, but this ended up being the cleanest, especially since the project I am working on already has C# components.

Answer (score 1):

I've never figured out how to do that, I don't think it's possible. It's as if you are expected to always be the one to create any event handler you might want to remove. Which is usually the case, this is the first time I've seen an API like this one which exposes the default handler as a member and then suggests you remove it if you don't want it - easy enough in C#, but a problem, apparently, in F# (but someone correct me if I'm wrong!)

The easiest solution is to handle the plot's `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` event, show your own context menu (or whatever) and set `e.Handled` to `true`. The preview events exist precisely to do this kind of thing.

(There might be other workarounds. You could try submitting a PR adding some public method like ClearDefaultMouseHandler() which would clear the handler, and can be called from F#.)

Don't forget that Shift-F10 is supposed to be the standard hotkey for showing a context menu. Presently ScottPlot doesn't implement that (or at least, I didn't see it). Since you want to control the context menu, you should be aware that at some point in the future it might support that key combination, and then a user could surprise you by bringing up the default context menu rather than yours using their keyboard. Or maybe you want to implement this yourself, either through a PR or just in your own code. Or maybe not, since if you have multiple plots, there's the question of which one has the focus. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C# generates a specific kind of `EventHandler` object with a direct pointer to the `fp.DefaultRightClickEvent` method - and so the method that removes the event can recognize the method and remove the handler.

I do not think there is a way to generate this in F# (at the moment), because F# will just always wrap method references into an anonymous lambda function.

I'm afraid I got a bit nerd sniped by this question - because you can of course look at the generated IL code and produce the same thing at runtime in F# using Reflection Emit. If there is any other solution, that is probably the way to go :-) but it turns out this actually works.

I have a very basic form with a plot on it:

```
let f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form()
let fp = new ScottPlot.FormsPlot()
f.Controls.Add(fp);
```

The following code generates a dynamic delegate that calls the remove method of the event in the right way:

```
open System.Reflection.Emit

type A = class end
let remove = new DynamicMethod("Remove",typeof<System.Void>,[|typeof<obj>|],typeof<A>.Module)
let il = remove.GetILGenerator()
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, typeof<ScottPlot.FormsPlot>.GetMethod("DefaultRightClickEvent"))
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof<System.EventHandler>.GetConstructors()[0])
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof<ScottPlot.FormsPlot>.GetEvent("RightClicked").RemoveMethod)
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
```

And now you just call it to get the handler removed!

```
remove.Invoke(null, [| box fp |]) |> ignore
```

I guess I found at least one thing that is easier to do in C# than in F#!

Comment: ew, looks horrid...I'd just write some C# code in a lib...almost as horrid, but at least its legible.

Comment: You could wrap this in a function and forget about it, but I agree, C# may be a bit nicer here!